# Ruby-Debug-Base gem gives error: "Ruby mach-o, ...wrong architecture"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to run a rake test, and when I do, I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4/lib/ruby_debug.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - 
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
```

I've searched online for hours - does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? I'm on OSX and have tried re-installing the ruby_debug and ruby_debug_base gems - still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can try uninstalling the gem, and installing it again by executing:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install ruby-debug-base -v=0.10.4
```

this will install the 64bit version, not sure if that's the prob... but hope it helps =)